# Inactive breakpoints with xPack gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints, xpack

I'm using Eclipse and xPack GNU Arm Embedded GCC. When I start debugging almost everything works, I can walk through my code, I can step into functions. The only issue is that I can't set any breakpoints [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgLW1.jpg) other than the one entered in the Startup page (_start). In fact, I can add a breakpoint but it's inactive and the debugger doesn't stop at it.
Please advise how to make them active.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the question is no longer active. The issue was that for unknown reasons the option Skip all breakpoints was activated.